# curl download multiple files with brace syntax

Tags: curl

I am trying to download two files by the following syntax:

```
curl -O http://domain/path/to/{file1,file2}
```

The problem is that only the first file is actually saved locally, and the second was simply printed to stdout.

I do realized that if I add a `-O` it works just fine:

```
curl -OO http://domain/path/to/{file1,file2}
```

But isn't this impractical if the number of files grows too big? For example,

```
curl -O http://domain/path/to/file[1,100]
```

My question is, is there really no way to download multiple individual files at once with `curl` (without adding a correct number of `-O`)?

Comment: Why not using a for loop or using wget instead?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro (1)Yes, I can use loop. I'm just curious if `curl` can achieve it. (2) I'm considering not only HTTP(s), FTP protocols, e.g. SFTP.

Comment: I mean, being such a powerful tool, why `curl` just fails at this not-so-hard functionality?

Comment: Just to make clear that the `{}` and `[]` (and also `*` and `?`) syntax is *shell* globbing/expansion, `curl` never gets to see them, it is the same as `curl url1 url2`

Comment: wget does not handle SSL

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This has been implemented in curl 7.19.0. See @Besworks answer.

According to the man page there is no way to keep the original file name except using multiple `O`s. Alternatively you could use your own file names:

```
curl http://{one,two}.site.example -o "file_#1.txt"
```

resulting in `http://one.site.example` being saved to `file_one.txt` and `http://two.site.example` being saved to `file_two.txt`.

Multiple variables even work. Like:

```
curl http://{site,host}.host[1-5].example -o "#1_#2"
```

resulting in `http://site.host1.example` being saved to `site_1`, `http://host.host1.example` being saved to `host_1` and so on.

Comment: Or you could do something like `curl -$(printf 'O%.0s' {1..3}) http://domain/path/to/{file1,file2,file3}`

Answer (score 43):

The `--remote-name-all` option tells curl to behave as if you used `-O` or `--remote-name` for each file. So this command does the trick:

```
curl --remote-name-all http://domain/path/to/{file1,file2}
```

Reference [here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--remote-name-all).

This option has been available since [version 7.19.0](https://curl.haxx.se/changes.html#7_19_0)

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is how the shell (likely BASH) is interpreting the `curl` command.

Basically, it is looking at

`curl -O http://domain/path/to/{file1,file2}`

and expanding it to:

`curl -O http://domain/path/to/file1 http://domain/path/to/file2`

This is a problem because the flag, `-O`, is applied only to the first instance and not to any that follow it.

This can be fixed by double quoting the url:

`curl -O "http://domain/path/to/{file1,file2}"`

The curl team have acknowledged this on [GitHub](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/5388) and PRs to both the man-page and the [official curl manual](https://ec.haxx.se/cmdline/cmdline-globbing) have been submitted so they should reflect this potential globbing behaviour in some shells in the future.

If you'd like an easy test case to see this failing and how to fix it then try downloading two zips of .txt files of *Moby Dick* from [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2701/).

Running:

`curl -O  https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2701/2701-{0,h}.zip`

will provide the following response:

`% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  500k  100  500k    0     0   380k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  380k
Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell 
Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output 
Warning: <FILE>" to save to a file.`

(If the files you were pulling were raw text then it would just dump to standard out, likely your screen, and that would be mean to do for *Moby Dick* and that's why the .zip files are being used instead.)

Running:

`curl -O  "https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2701/2701-{0,h}.zip"`

will give something like this output instead:

`[1/2]: https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2701/2701-0.zip --> 2701-0.zip
--_curl_--https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2701/2701-0.zip
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  500k  100  500k    0     0   407k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  407k`

`[2/2]: https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2701/2701-h.zip --> 2701-h.zip
--_curl_--https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2701/2701-h.zip
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  522k  100  522k    0     0  1000k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 1000k`

Note that this problem only arises when `{ }` are used for globbing.  If only `[ ]` are used then the double quotes are not needed.

Incidentally, if `wget` is installed it can likely handle the globbing without the need for quotes.

Running:

`wget http://domain/path/to/{file1,file2}`

would pull down both files (if they actually existed).

Running:

`wget https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2701/2701-{0,h}.zip`

will pull down the Moby Dick zip files as per the double-quoted `curl` example, above.

Answer (score 2):

There is an alternative way to download multiple files with curl:

```bsh
urls="firstUrl secondUrl thirdUrl" 
for url in $urls
do
   curl -O "$url"
done
```

*Note*: the mandatory space is used to delimit different URLs.